# Removing library from Gradle causes "no resource found" errors

Tags: android, gradle, compiler-errors, dependencies

Below I've attached 2 screenshots: the first one shows my gradle file, the second one shows the errors. When I remove the chatkit dependency, I get the errors in the second screenshot even though the library is not being used anywhere. Why is this happening?

[image: Grade File with problematic library/dependency highlighted]

[image: Errors after removing the problematic library]

Comment: Your `R` file probably needs rebuilding, do a Build --> Rebuild Project

Comment: Yes tried cleaning and Rebuilding. No change in the errors.

Answer (score 0):

have you performed a clean project before to re-build the app?

On menu build -> Clean project?

Comment: Yes tried. Didn't work. Tried cleaning and rebuilding. No change in the errors